# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'team' of null

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this game I'm making and I'm using ajax call to php to get items from the database, but I getting getting an error so the preloader doesn't go away, and I get this error when i view the resources on Chrome : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'team' of null". Any idea why it's doing this?
Jquery:

```
function appendTeam(){

$.ajax({

       url : _path + "/core/ajax.php",
       type : 'POST',
       data : { f: 'getTeam'},
       dataType : 'json',
       success :  function(data) {

        if(data) {


            return false;
        } else{
            var count = 0;
            $.each(data.team, function(i, c){
                // check
                if(!$('#'+c)) return true;
                var element = $('#'+c);
                $('input[name="s'+i+'"]').val(element.attr('id'));
                $('.slot.'+(i+1)).append(element);
                element.data('prevParent', $('.slot.'+(i+1)));
                count ++;

            });

            appendStatus(count);
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#preloader').fadeOut('fast',function(){
                    $('#preloader').remove();
                    popUp('match');
                });
            }, 2000);


        }

    }
});
}
```

Php:

```
if (isset($_POST['getTeam'])) {
$team = array();
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE id = '1'")  or die(mysql_error());


while ($teams = mysql_fetch_array( $sql )) {

$chara1 = $team['cid1'];
$chara2 = $team['cid2'];
$chara3 = $team['cid3'];

}
$team = json_encode(array(
'chara1' => $chara1,
'chara2' => $chara2,
'chara3' => $chara3
));
echo $team;
}
```

And I want it to echo the team, if he has a team already selected in these div elements :

```
<div id="droppable_slots" class="current_team">
                    <div class="slot 1">1</div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="s0" value="10">
                    <div class="slot 2">2</div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="s1" value="7">
                    <div class="slot 3">3</div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="s2" value="3">
                </div>
```

Comment: I don't think your PHP code is returning valid JSON, and even if it were I don't see anything creating an object property called "team".

Comment: How would i make it so that it returns a valid JSON?

Comment: You probably mean `if( !data) {` Also, return statements do not work in `success`

Comment: the error says `data` is null, i suggest upgrading jQuery so that in this case jQuery will properly throw an error message `parseerror` since your json is invalid.

Comment: @KevinB actually I misread the code.  The code as it stands won't really do very much; the `while` loop references "$team" instead of "$teams" to look at each row, and "$team" is therefore always empty.  The loop just echoes out a single object with empty values.  Basically, it's kind-of a long way from working.

Comment: isn't the error happening in the javascript, not the php? well, the error he's reporting anyway. property `team` of `null` suggests to me that `data` is null since that is the only place where he's using `team` as a property in the javascript. And, if `data` is null, then he's using an older version of jquery and the php returned nothing.

Comment: @KevinB if you look at the PHP (and note that I'm not a PHP programmer, but this seems pretty obvious), there's just one thing echoed to the output, and that's a single JSON object without a property called "team".

Comment: Right, but it's not saying team is undefined on an object, it's saying `team` is undefined on `null` *"Cannot read property 'team' **of null**"* But yes, there are errors in the php that are likely leading to data being null..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the wrong key in the post data -- it should be "f", not "getTeam".  (Note that the Ajax call is sending `data : { f: 'getTeam'}`.)  Presumably you meant this:

```
if (isset($_POST['f']) && $_POST['f'] == 'getTeam')
```

Another typo: `if (data) return false` will return false when there *is* data -- should be the opposite:

```
if(data && data.team) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: It works but now i get this :Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/kenchix1/public_html/game/core/ajax.php on line 19
{"chara1":null,"chara2":null,"chara3":null}

Comment: @karthikr not sure what you mean -- `return` won't exit the function?  It doesn't really matter anyway in this case, as the "else" block will still not get executed.

Comment: This is a little redundant. If data doesn't exist, then data.team for sure doesn't exist!  Why check for both?

Comment: @karthikr that's a separate problem -- it probably suggests that your query failed somehow.  See here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/2973209/1001985

Comment: returning false or true doesn't matter, the point is it exits the function.

Comment: @KevinB ok point taken, but it's somewhat tangential to the OP -- the key point is that the function should proceed if there is data.

Comment: Yes, i was agreeing with you more or less. re-inforcing that returning anything (true or false or nothing) will exit the function, which is what is (was) wanted in that situation. you've since updated to not use a return.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is here:

```
if (data) {  
    return false;   // returns false if data exists
} else {
   // data does not exist in this block
   var count=0;
   $.each(data.team ...
   ... //
}
```

*Basically*, because of your if/else block isn't formed properly.  This should fix it...

```
if (!data) {
    return false;
} else {
    ... // work with data here
}
```

also you need this:

```
mysql_fetch_array($con, $sql);
```

If you are going to use the procedural functions you will need to pass your connection resource ($con = mysql_connect) to the function.  If you use the object oriented approach, you do not need to pass the resource as a parameter.